How to use an attribute as a type guard in a TypeScript class with generics?
How can I use a class generic to determine the type of a conditional type?
Below is a barebone example and TS playground link.
How can I call this.b and this.a without using as or any other manual correction?
type X<T> = T extends true ? number : string;

export class A<UN extends boolean, I extends X<UN>> {
  useNumber: UN;

  constructor(useNumber: UN) {
    this.useNumber = useNumber;
  }

  a(input: string): string {
    return `${input}j`;
  }

  b(input: number): number {
    return input * 2;
  }

  c(input: I): string {
    // I expected `UN` generic type (`this.useNumber`) is used as a type guard below.
    //.          =.      UN       ?       I       :       I
    //           =       UN       ?    X<true>    :    X<false>
    //           =       UN       ?    number     :    string
    const result = this.useNumber ? this.b(input) : this.a(input);
    return result.toString();
  }
}

TypeScript Playground

Why yould you vote to close this with Needs details or clarity? The question could not be clearer.

@jonrsharpe, why did you remove "typescript generics" and "typeguards" tags? Question is about how to create a typeguard using the typescript generics.

Currently this isn't possible directly; TS doesn't modify generic types like UN in response to checking generic values like this.useNumber; that would need ms/TS#33014 to work. You'd need to refactor this to something quite different if you want to express such a constraint. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz could you please suggest a workaround if possible? I try to create a class that depends a type similar to the exmple UN. In my real case, the types are more complex and it is unconvienient to expect the subclasses use as. I will appriciate a workaround without as, I can accept different refactoring. My only constaint is not using manual type corrections, because of complexity.

You could try to do something like this to force TS to treat this as a discriminated union with useNumber as the discriminant, but it's yucky. Your approach is really fighting against the TS type system; if you conceptually have a discriminated union then write that union to start with, like this, without trying to make classes be generic unions themselves.  Does that fully address the question now or am I still missing something?

@jcalz, thank you for the answers. You are right. The first example is fighting against TS, and the second example is my current situation. I was trying to merge two classes into one class.
I will accept your answer. Could you please create an answer and add your two previous comments.

I will do so when I get a chance.

Currently this isn't possible directly; TypeScript doesn't directly modify generic types like UN in response to checking generic values like this.useNumber.  In other words, TypeScript cannot use control flow analysis to affect generic type parameters.  There's an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#33014 to support this, and it might even be implemented soon-ish (it's mentioned in the TypeScript 5.5 roadmap at microsoft/TypeScript#57475) but for now it doesn't work that way.
So in this.useNumber ? this.b(input) : this.a(input), while useNumber is true in the true branch and false in the false branch, UN stays stubbornly the same and cannot be constrained to either true or false. So I is still up in the air and it doesn't work.

By far the easiest fix is to use type assertions or the like to just push through.
If you want to convince TypeScript to follow the logic, you mostly have to demonstrate that this is a discriminated union where useNumber is the discriminant. Perhaps like this:
c(
  this: { useNumber: true, b(input: X<UN>): number } | 
        { useNumber: false, a(input: X<UN>): string },
  input: X<UN>) {
  const result = this.useNumber ? this.b(input) : this.a(input);
  return result.toString();
}

I've used a this parameter to tell the compiler that the c method can only be used on instances that are of the discriminated union type specified.  Once UN is specified as either true or false, the compiler can indeed verify that, so the following calls work:
const n = new A(true);
n.c(3); // okay

const s = new A(false);
s.c("abc"); // okay

That works, but it's not idiomatic TypeScript at all. It's fighting against the language. Class declarations can't be discriminated unions. The more idiomatic way to do this with classes is to use inheritance for polymorphism and make a union of the subclasses if you need it:
abstract class ABase {
  a(input: string): string {
    return `${input}j`;
  }

  b(input: number): number {
    return input * 2;
  }
}

class ATrue extends ABase {
  readonly useNumber = true;
  c(input: number) {
    return this.b(input).toString();
  }
}

class AFalse extends ABase {
  readonly useNumber = false;
  c(input: string) {
    return this.a(input).toString();
  }
}

type A = ATrue | AFalse;

let a: A;

a = new ATrue();
a.c(3); // okay

a = new AFalse();
a.c("abc"); // okay

So it depends on your use case how you want to proceed. If you need to represent this behavior as a single class, you'll either need to jump through weird hoops, or just use a type assertion.
Playground link to code
